# Send notification on particular field change in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, notifications

I want to send e-mail from SQL Server when a particular column is updated with new info.

I am using this trigger which I also found here and it works, but for all `LastEventTime` column changes.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Users]
ON [dbo].[Users]
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
    IF (UPDATE (LastEventTime))
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
                  @profile_name = 'SQL Admin', 
                  @recipients = 'email@email.com', 
                  @body = 'Someone made a change to data in the table', 
                  @subject = 'Check this out!'; 
GO
```

I want to use this trigger for a particular column in a row on a table.

Comment: While you *can* send emails from SQL Server, this is something best done elsewhere - and definitely not within a *trigger*.

Comment: Remember that IF UPDATE(columnName) is only indicating that the column name APPEARED in an UPDATE statement; it doesn't mean that the value was actually changed.

Also remember that triggers in SQL Server are fired for each UPDATE (in your case) command, whether 1 or a million rows are being UPDATEd.

So if your volume is low enough for this to not impact performance too much, you would need a CURSOR inside the trigger to handle multiple rows and check to see if the column was actually changed.

BUT... as you said the trigger above "works", what else do you want it to do?